# OrderBy() and OrderByDescending() is stable in C# API Parse?

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I have been trying to order my table data in some way or another, but the methods the Parse recommends for ordering, such as `.OrderBy()` and `.OrderByDescending()` have no effect. They both give the same output. It does no ordering just outputs the data as it is.

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("tableName").OrderBy("createdAt");
```

OR

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("tableName").OrderByDescending("createdAt");
```

These methods have the same output, which it shouldn't, as the methods mention: one should be ordered ascending and the other one descending.

Has anyone encountered this and has find a replacement for those methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that even though ordering with Parse methods does not work, using LINQ instead in Parse you will get the expected outcome.

You will have to write something like:

```
var query = from tabledata in ParseObject.GetQuery("tableName")
            orderby tabledata.Get<DateTime>("createdAt") descending
            select tabledata;
```

And it orders it correctly.

Comment: Here you are casting all data to `DateTime` objects which you don't do in the fluent syntax example. Please make a reproducable example .

Comment: I am not doing so, I am saying that in tabledata the "createdAt" column is of type DateTime and to order by that column. Even more explained would be: I get object tabledata from table with all the columns and from this object get column "createdAt" of type DateTime and order by it. It's the Parse syntax for LINQ.

Comment: I am actually using this exact code in my project, except the name's table